# Raft Vs MongoDB Primary Election

Tags: mongodb, consensus, raft

How is the [raft consensus algorithm](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/download/attachments/11370504/raft.pdf) different from MongoDB's primary election process other than the fact that MongoDB takes other factors (priority, for example) into consideration while electing the primary?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some key differences on the consensus approach as at MongoDB 2.4 are:

- Raft uses a *strong leader* model. The leader has responsibility for managing replication and data flows from the leader to other servers.  In MongoDB replica sets the secondaries follow the operation log (*oplog*) of an upstream host which can either be the primary or a secondary with a newer oplog.
- Raft only has three node states to consider: leader (primary), follower (secondary), or candidate (nominated primary). MongoDB has [additional node states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/) to consider including more potential error states such as `RECOVERING` or `SHUNNED` nodes, or [delayed replica set members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-delayed-replica-set-member/).
- In Raft each node can only vote for a candidate node once per election term. MongoDB allows votes per node to be adjusted as part of the replica set configuration, so some nodes may be non-voting or possibly have multiple votes (Note: multiple vote configuration has been deprecated as of the [MongoDB 2.5 development branch](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10513)).
- Raft uses a *joint consensus* approach which allows a cluster to continue operating during configuration changes.  MongoDB requires a strict majority of voting nodes to elect a new primary; while an election is in progress the replica set has no primary and cannot accept writes.

For more detailed information you should compare the Raft paper [In Search of an Understandable Consensus Algorithm](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/download/attachments/11370504/raft.pdf) with the documentation on [MongoDB Replica Set Elections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/).